# Is $\pi$ algebraic over $\mathbb Q_p$ via some embedding of $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C_p$ embedding?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

It is known that $e$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q_p$ via Taylor expansion of $e^p$ through $e$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Consider $\mathbb Q_p$ local fields and real number $\pi\in \mathbb C_p$ and $\mathbb Q_p\subset \mathbb C_p$ with $\mathbb C\subset \mathbb C_p$ fixed embedding. Is $\pi$ algebraic over $\mathbb Q_p$? It is known that $\pi$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

$\textbf{Q':}$ According to the comments below, it seems that there is potentially embedding of $\mathbb C\to \mathbb C_p$ s.t. $\pi$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q_p$. Why should I expect so? I would hope to treat all embedding equally but it seems there is a difference. Any intuitive reason?

Comment: How do you define $\pi$ in $\mathbf Q_p$ ?

Comment: How so you define $\pi$? E.g., I suppose you define $e$ as $\sum\frac1{n!}$ and not as $\lim (1+\frac 1n)^n$ (which would not converge in $\Bbb Q_p$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I will define $e$ as its taylor expansion.

Comment: @Max I mean take $C\subset C_p$. Clearly $\pi\in C_p$. Is $\pi$ even algebraic over $Q_p$?

Comment: When you say "Take $C\subset C_p$" ... is there a canonical embedding of $C$ into $C_p$?

Comment: @GEdgar There is no canonical but you have to pick one.

Comment: So, $\pi$ may be algebraic over $Q_p$ using some embeddings, and not using others?

Comment: @GEdgar I am not sure why I should expect $\pi$ may be algebraic over $Q_p$ using "some embedding". Is there a reason why I should expect so? Why I cannot treat all embedding on equal footing here? I would hope if it is algebraic over one embedding, it is algebraic over other embeddings.(Is this part wrong for infinite extension case?)

Comment: @user45765 $\pi$ is algebraic with some embedding and not with the other because both embeddings don't send the same field to $Q_p$. As a field without its topology $Q_p$ is just an algebraic extension of some purely transcendental extension of $Q$ generated by many elements. Pick any $a \in Q_p$ transcendental over $Q$ and send $Q(\pi)$ to $Q(a)$.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/a/17656/100961